# Find Partition key of the SSTables

Tags: cassandra

In the `nodetool getsstables` documentation write about partition key of sstables. How could I find it?

https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/3.0/cassandra/tools/toolsGetSstables.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your partition key can be found in the table description.

If you have access to the Cassandra shell, you could do the following to find the table description, for example (my keyspace is `animals` and my table is `types`:

```
cqlsh> desc animals.types;

CREATE TABLE animals.types (
    id uuid PRIMARY KEY,
    color text,
    type text
)
```

The partition key is `id` in this simple table.

Example id:

```
cqlsh> select * from animals.types;
 id                                   | color   | type
 14fc1189-cb57-4e83-baca-ee178e605af1 |  orange |  giraffe
```

Use that in getsstables like the following:

```
# nodetool getsstables animals types 14fc1189-cb57-4e83-baca-ee178e605af1
/var/lib/cassandra/data/animals/types-6ef0da00659911e88803df4f403979ef/mc-1-big-Data.db
```

Comment: if the partition key has multiple columns you can use `:` to put them together